# How to manually make tables using booktabs

Tags: tables, formatting, multicolumn, booktabs, xtable

I am really new in the use of LaTex and would like some help to make this table using `booktabs` formatting. I use `R` and would ideally generate it using `xtables` package. However, I could not deal with the column spanning thing.

That is why I tried to manually insert `\multicolumn` command.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}


 \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}llccccccc}
\toprule   
{} & {} & {Observations} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Median}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SD}\\
 \cline{3-3} 
 \cline{4-6} 
 \cline{7-9} 
 Year & Group & N & V1 & V2 & V3 & V1 & V2 & V3 \\ 
   \hline
   \multirow{2}{*}{2012}
  & Control & 2 & 0.052 & 0.294 & 0.115 & 0.304 & 0.619 & 0.611 \\ 
  & Treat & 2 & 0.511 & 0.083 & 0.123 & 0.573 & 0.541 & 0.734 \\ 
  \multirow{2}{*}{2016}
  & Control & 3 & 0.320 & 0.344 & 0.382 & 0.382 & 0.494 & 0.477 \\ 
  & Treat & 3 & 0.378 & 0.296 & 0.123 & 0.386 & 0.668 & 0.732 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Mean by Year and Group} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, I think this table is not really well formatted, not according to `booktabs` standards, is it? How to make manually a table with the same design, but better formatted?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\multirow` is also valid in booktabs, but read the manual for design suggestions. You should avoid commands like `\cline` and `\hline` and use their equivalents however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem with the table is that you are not using the `booktabs` rules, but instead a mixture of standard tabular rules (`\hline` and `\cline`) and `booktabs` rules (`\toprule`).

Replacing these rules with the `booktabs` versions (`\midrule`,  `\cmidrule` and `\bottomrule`) gives you the nice formatting you want.

I've removed the `multirow` stuff. This adds nothing to your table; it's perfectly clear just to put the year on the first row of the pairs of rows for that year.  In general I would avoid using `multirow` at all. It has its uses, but usually for things like forms that have boxed cells. For standard research tables it's almost never appropriate.

P.S. I hope the data is made up! Your Ns are really small... :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}


 \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}llccccccc}
\toprule   
{} & {} & {Observations} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Median}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SD}\\
 \cmidrule{3-3} 
 \cmidrule{4-6} 
 \cmidrule{7-9} 
 Year & Group & N & V1 & V2 & V3 & V1 & V2 & V3 \\ 
\midrule
2012  & Control & 2 & 0.052 & 0.294 & 0.115 & 0.304 & 0.619 & 0.611 \\ 
  & Treat & 2 & 0.511 & 0.083 & 0.123 & 0.573 & 0.541 & 0.734 \\ 
2016  & Control & 3 & 0.320 & 0.344 & 0.382 & 0.382 & 0.494 & 0.477 \\ 
  & Treat & 3 & 0.378 & 0.296 & 0.123 & 0.386 & 0.668 & 0.732 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Mean by Year and Group} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Some comments on typesetting numeric data

Using the `c` column type is really not the best plan when you're typesetting numeric data. Usually we want numeric data to be aligned in some way, so that if the numbers are of different sizes, they line up properly.

For decimal data, it's normal to line up on the decimal point. For non-decimal data, simple right alignment is fine.

To align with the decimal point, you can use the `siunitx` package or the `dcolumn` package. `siunitx` has many fancy capabilities for formatting numeric data automatically, including digit grouping for large numbers. It also provides ways of properly typesetting SI units.   The `dcolumn` package is designed specifically for decimal point alignment.  Here's an example to show you the differences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Shorthand for multicolumn
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccrD{.}{.}{2.3}S}
\toprule
Center & Center & \mc{right} & \mc{D-column} & \mc{S-column}  \\
\midrule
1 & 32.6 & 1 & 32.6 & 32.6  \\
10 & 335.434 & 10 & 335.434 & 335.434  \\
100 & 0.99 & 100 & 0.99 & 0.99  \\
5 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 1  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample]

Comment: Thank you! They are just an example, later I will deal with the original dataset.

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito I would also tend not to use `c` columns for numbers, `r` columns are more sensible, or even smarter columns like those provided in the `siunitx` package.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? I am really a novice on this

Comment: @AlanMunn: Where are the grey `\cmidrule`s in your code?

Comment: @Bernard There are none. It must be an artefact of the screenshot.

Comment: @Arthur Carvalho Brito: what Alan Munn means, I think, is that decimal values should be aligned on the decimal dot. If *all* numbers have the same number of digits before this decimal dot and the same number after it, `c` will be fine. Otherwise  the are package to set this problem, most notably `dcolumn`, `numprint` and `siunitx`.

Comment: @Alan Munn:  Too bad! I find tables lighter when intermediate rules are greyed.

Comment: What is the difference between d-column and s-column?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito The `S` column comes from `siunitx` and can do more sophisticated things like accommodating non-numeric elements after a number but still getting alignment right. The `D` column comes from the `dcolumn` package and mainly aligns numbers on their decimal point.

Comment: @AlanMunn how can I implement dcolumn on the columns with decimal values on my table?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito If your data are uniformly to three decimal places the `c` column you used is fine. But if you have differing numbers of decimal places, you can replace your `c` column with `D{.}{.}{n.m}` where *n* is the max number of digits before the decimal and *m* the max number of digits after.

Answer (score 8):

First all your rules should be done with `booktabs`, as it adds some padding to your table rules (table rows in basic latex of often much too tight).

Second, table captions should be *above* tables, as tables may spread over pages, and readers shouldn't have to turn the page to know what the table is about. For this the caption `package` is useful, basic latex forgets to swap the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` when the caption is over the table.

Third, I would replace `Observations` with an abbreviation, as I find it ugly to have a column of single digits with a such a wide column head.

Fourth, I would set a smaller intercolumn space for the two groups of 3 columns at the end of the table. Also, the `(lr)` parameter for `\cmidrules is usefule here to improve the general look of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow, caption, booktabs}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[ht]
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Mean by Year and Group}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}llc*{2}{c@{\enspace}c@{\enspace}c}}
\toprule
{} & {} & {Obsv\textsuperscript{ns}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Median} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SD}\\
 \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
 \cmidrule{4-6}
 \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
 Year & Group & N & V1 & V2 & V3 & V1 & V2 & V3 \\
   \midrule
   \multirow{2}{*}{2012}
  & Control & 2 & 0.052 & 0.294 & 0.115 & 0.304 & 0.619 & 0.611 \\
  & Treat & 2 & 0.511 & 0.083 & 0.123 & 0.573 & 0.541 & 0.734 \\
\addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{*}{2016}
  & Control & 3 & 0.320 & 0.344 & 0.382 & 0.382 & 0.494 & 0.477 \\
  & Treat & 3 & 0.378 & 0.296 & 0.123 & 0.386 & 0.668 & 0.732 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: If you don't want to abbreviate `Observations, you should consider reorganising the table  swapping rows and columns.