# Aligning values to columns after using siunitx

Tags: tables, formatting, vertical-alignment, siunitx

based on the [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380233/how-to-manually-make-tables-using-booktabs/380237?noredirect=1#comment941454_380237) discussion, I made the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Mean by Year and Group}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}llc*{2}{S@{\enspace}S@{\enspace}S}}
\toprule   
{} & {} & {Sample} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Median}  & \multicolumn{3}   {c}{SD}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-3} 
\cmidrule(lr){4-6} 
\cmidrule(lr){7-9} 
Year & Group & N & V1 & V2 & V3 & V1 & V2 & V3 \\ 
\midrule
   2012  & Control & 2 & 10.052 & 0.294 & 10000.115 & 0.04 & 0.619 & 0.611 \\ 
         & Treat & 2 & 0.511 & 0.083 & 0.123 & 0.573 & 0.541 & 0.734 \\ 
   2016  & Control & 3 & 0.320 & 0.344 & 0.382 & 0.382 & 0.494 & 0.477 \\ 
         & Treat & 3 & 0.378 & 0.296 & 0.123 & 0.386 & 0.668 & 0.732 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Can someone help me make the `V1`, `V2`and `V3` columns be aligned to the values on each column? I mean, after using `siunitx` package the column titles are aligned to the beggining of the number and not to its center.

Comment: Enclose your V1, V2, V3 in braces will be sufficient.

Comment: @Troy (+1) Better than my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is to use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{..}`, but enclosing your `V1`, `V2`, and `V3` in braces is a better solution given by @Troy in a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}    

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\M}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Mean by Year and Group}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}llc*{2}{S@{\enspace}S@{\enspace}S}}
\toprule   
{} & {} & {Sample} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Median}  & \multicolumn{3}   {c}{SD}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-3} 
\cmidrule(lr){4-6} 
\cmidrule(lr){7-9} 
Year & Group & N & \M{V1} & \M{V2} & \M{V3} & \M{V1} & \M{V2} & \M{V3} \\ 
\midrule
   2012  & Control & 2 & 10.052 & 0.294 & 10000.115 & 0.04 & 0.619 & 0.611 \\ 
         & Treat & 2 & 0.511 & 0.083 & 0.123 & 0.573 & 0.541 & 0.734 \\ 
   2016  & Control & 3 & 0.320 & 0.344 & 0.382 & 0.382 & 0.494 & 0.477 \\ 
         & Treat & 3 & 0.378 & 0.296 & 0.123 & 0.386 & 0.668 & 0.732 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```